# Access: User entered Value to Label

Tags: forms, ms-access, textbox, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to take a value entered in`Form1` from a user, and then take that value and turn it into a label in `Form2`. So for example, if the user enters "Apple" in `Textbox1` in `Form1`, how would I grab that value and enter it into `Label1` in `Form2`.

I know code to change a label is

```
Private Sub Command56_Click()
    Label1.Caption = "Something else"
End Sub
```

but I'm not sure how to get a user entered value from another form.

Comment: Have you checked out how to reference another form's controls?

Comment: are both forms opened at the same time when you want to do this? Something like `Forms("Form2").Label1.Caption=Forms("Form1").Textbox1.value` should work, if both are opened.

Comment: @fbueckert i've written multiple queries such as this... but I really just followed a template and didn't learn how or why it worked `INSERT INTO Person_Name
VALUES (Forms![Person_Name]![Person_Name_ID], Forms![Person_Name]![Prefix], Forms![Person_Name]![First_Name], Forms![Person_Name]![Middle_Name], Forms![Person_Name]![Last_Name], Forms![Person_Name]![Suffix], Forms![Person_Name]![Timestamp]);`

Comment: Does it error? Does it work?  We don't have much indication about what you've tried, and if it does or doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be:

```
Private Sub Command56_Click()
    Label1.Caption = Nz(Forms("Form1").Textbox1.Value)
End Sub
```

Nz prevents an error should Textbox1 be empty (Null).

Comment: Perfect one. I would add this would work only if both forms (the one containing the button `Command56_Click` and `Form1`) are opened at same time. If `Form1`is not loaded, it won't work.

Comment: The form would be opened at the same time so that would work!